# ¿Qué quiere decir !! en Bash?

Tags: bash, línea-de-comandos

He encontrado los siguientes comandos pero no sé qué hacen por mucho que he buscado información al respecto:

```
$!-1
$!!
$!7
```

¿Alguien me podría clarificar su uso?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ahí creo que te pueden ayudar

Comment: Deberías centrar esfuerzos en una única pregunta. Si tienes dos, deberías abrir dos preguntas.

Comment: ¿Los has ejecutado? ¿Dónde los has encontrado? ¿En qué contexto? Pista --> [Bash bang commands](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/bash-bang-commands)

Comment: muchas gracias fedorqui, he encontrado lo q buscaba.

Answer (score 3):

En la consola tienes una serie de atajos para repetir un comando ejecutado previamente.

- `!!` ejecuta el último comando que ejecutaste
- `!-n` ejecuta el n-ésimo comando anterior

  - `!-1` ejecuta el comando anterior, luego es lo mismo que `!!`
- `!n` ejecuta el comando que aparece en n.ª posición en tu historial de comandos

Veamos ejemplos:

```
$ echo 1
1
$ !!
echo 1        # <-- nos imprime el comando que volverá a ejecutar
1
```

```
$ echo hola
hola
$ echo adios
adios
$ !-2
echo hola     # <-- nos imprime el comando que volverá a ejecutar
hola
```

```
$ echo 44
44
$ history | tail
  502  history | less
  503  echo 44     # <-- el comando está en la posición 503.ª del histórico
  504  history | tail
$ !503         # <-- así que ejecutamos ese comando, el 503.º
echo 44
44
```

Creo que con esto tienes suficientes elementos para entender este chiste :)

[image: make me a sandwich, sudo bang bang]

Existe una serie de comandos alrededor de esto muy recomendados que puedes leer en [Bang Bang - Command Recall in Linux](http://web.archive.org/web/20130731111822if_/https://craig-russell.co.uk/2011/09/28/bang-bang-command-recall-in-linux.html)

Comment: mil gracias a todos por responder.

Comment: recuerda que puedes aceptar la respuesta si resolvió tu problema